# Laravel5.4 - How to use POST method insert data to database

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I try to insert data to data.

```
  public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('request_song', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('song_name', 150);
                    $table->string('singer_name', 50);
                    $table->string('general_input', 200);

                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
```

RequestSongModel

```
class RequestSongModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'request_song';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'song_name',
        'singer_name'
    ];

}
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rule = [
            'song_name' => 'required',
            'singer_name' => 'required',

        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rule);
        $requestSong = RequestSongModel::created($request->all());

        return response()->json(['DATA' => $requestSong], 201);
    }
```

When I insert, it response null.

> {
>       "DATA": null }

I don't know, why it response null.
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

`$requestSong = RequestSongModel::created($request->all());`

to

`$requestSong = RequestSongModel::create($request->all());`

Comment: To clarify: `created` is an event thrown by Eloquent the ORM while `create` actually creates the model.